# Error django MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: python, django

Tengo un error al actualizar me sale, no tengo problemas al crear ni eliminar solo al actualizar un registro.

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/crud/edit/update/2
Django Version: 1.11.6
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
"'lat'"
Exception Location: C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 85
Python Executable:  C:\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Naoto\\web',
 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 4 Nov 2017 22:05:02 +0000
```

Por si sirve de algo, mi views.py de mi aplicación.

```
  from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from .models import Member

    # Create your views here.

    def index(request):
        members = Member.objects.all()
        context = {'members': members}
        return render(request, 'crud/index.html', context)

    def create(request):
        member = Member(nomb=request.POST['nomb'], address=request.POST['address'], 
        lat=request.POST['lat'], lng=request.POST['lng'], tipo=request.POST['tipo'])
        member.save()
        return redirect('/')

    def edit(request, id):
        members = Member.objects.get(id=id)
        context = {'members': members}
        return render(request, 'crud/edit.html', context)

    def update(request, id):
        member = Member.objects.get(id=id)
        member.nomb     = request.POST['nomb']
        member.address  = request.POST['address']
        member.lat      = request.POST['lat'],
        member.lng      = request.POST['lng'],
        member.tipo     = request.POST['tipo']
        member.save()
        return redirect('/crud/')

    def delete(request, id):
        member = Member.objects.get(id=id)
        member.delete()
        return redirect('/crud/')

Y por si acaso mi model.py de la app

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.dasd

class Member(models.Model):
    nomb    = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    lat     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)
    lng     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6)
    tipo    = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nomb + " " + self.address + " " + self.lat + " " + self.lng + " " + self.tipo
```

Intente cambiar

```
 def update(request, id):
        member = Member.objects.get(id=id)
        member.nomb     = request.POST['nomb']
        member.address  = request.POST['address']
        member.lat      = request.POST['lat'],
        member.lng      = request.POST['lng'],
        member.tipo     = request.POST['tipo']
        member.save()
        return redirect('/crud/')
```

por esto pero no me actualiza  en los campos Direccion y Tipo me pone False y no me actualiza aunque hay odificado otro campo

```
def update(request, id):
    member = Member.objects.get(id=id)
    member.nomb     = request.POST.get('nomb',False)
    member.address  = request.POST.get('address', False)
    member.lat      = request.POST.get('lat', False)
    member.lng      = request.POST.get('lng', False)
    member.tipo     = request.POST.get('tipo', False)
    member.save()
    return redirect('/crud/')
```

Y aprovechando esta pregunta yo tengo mi superusuario pero si pongo localhost:8000/admin es mi pagina para logueo, pero si no me logueo y pongo directamente localhost:8000/crud me entra a mi pagina como evito esto? de una manera sencilla esto es lo primero que hago

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que le estas mandando una tupla, para python cuando declaras una variable con una coma al final, python considera una tupla, por ejemplo:

```
a = x,
```

para python esta declaración es equivalente a:

```
a = (x, '')
```

y el campo en tu modelo no acepta tuplas, tienes que quitar la coma al final.

En cuanto a tu segunda pregunta, para que solo usuarios registrados puedan acceder a tus vistas te aconsejo usar el decorador @login_required().
Ejemplo:

```
@login_required()
def update(request, id):
        member = Member.objects.get(id=id)
        member.nomb     = request.POST['nomb']
        member.address  = request.POST['address']
        member.lat      = request.POST['lat']
        member.lng      = request.POST['lng']
        member.tipo     = request.POST['tipo']
        member.save()
        return redirect('/crud/')
```

Magia negra de python y Django, una belleza.

Saludos.

Adrian.

Comment: le quite la coma pero me sigue arrojando el error y con lo otro por la consola me sale un mensaje diciendome   File "C:\Users\Naoto\web\crud\views.py", line
    @login_required()
NameError: name 'login_required' is not defined

Comment: sabes que me di cuenta que mi views.py de la app en la estructura html tenia todos los inputs o de latitud (lat) hacia abajo con el name address jaja asi que lo deje asi     marks.nomb     = request.POST.get('nomb')
    marks.address  = request.POST.get('address')
    marks.lat      = request.POST.get('lat')
    marks.lng      = request.POST.get('lng')
    marks.tipo     = request.POST.get('tipo')
y ya funciona bien, sigo con lo del lgin jaja

Comment: Debes añadir un import en tu archivo de `views.py` que es `from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required`

Comment: son grandes ambos :D , ahora dos cositas lo podria redirigir a la pagina de logeo si no lo encuentra? y por cierto cuando vaya a subir mi proyecto al servidor como hago? porque django me creo unas talas en mi base de datos entonces no se en ese caso

Comment: Para redirigir a la pagina de logueo en el decorador login_required(login_url='/tu_url_del_login') 
Saludos.

Comment: Hola @AdrianMansilla, tu afirmación es incorrecta: `a = (x, '')`, no es equivalente a eso. Simplemente es equivalente a una tupla de un elemento: `a = (x,)`

Comment: Tienes razón, pero no sabia como mas explicar, aunque no viene al caso en la pregunta, creo. Saludos.